# how to change background-color of the navigation-bar into different colours

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

How would I change the background color of each home-project-etc?

I have been able to change the first home nav one but can't seem to work out how to change the rest I think it got something to do with the first child, second child etc, only been learning few months, any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this and improve your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/     this is what im working from

Comment: @JayClarke - I'm sure we don't understand your question. well, I'm have no clue what you are asking. Maybe show us some of your code? Maybe try to describe your question in more detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create a class:
`.nav-justified > li > a{
  background-image: none;
  }`

Then for each of your home....project etc tabs, create a unique class then pass your background color there and set the background-image to none.

```css
.nav-justified > li.project-tab > a{
  background-color: #1da1f2;
  background-image: none;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="project-tab"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```